# What is the meaning of "grand large"

Tags: expressions, expressions-idiomatiques, étymologie

I encountered the expression

*des ballades au grand large*.

What does it mean? What is its etymology?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

« Le large » a un sens qui signifie *La haute mer*, par opposition à *la côte.*

« Le grand large » est une emphase de *la haute mer*.

Comment: Il peut aussi s'agir d'une fleuve? Ou sans eau du tout?

Comment: @Karlo: Éventuellement mais cette expression est utilisée généralement pour différencier la côte de la haute mer.

Answer (score 1):

@Toto's answer is fine. As a side remark, a little of googling gave:

> [Décidément attiré par le grand large, le jeune Chirac embarque comme marin sur un cargo, avant que son père ne le ramène dans le droit chemin.](https://www.nouvelobs.com/politique/elections-2007/20070515.OBS7332/le-parcours-politique-de-jacques-chirac.html#:~:text=D%C3%A9cid%C3%A9ment%20attir%C3%A9%20par%20le%20grand,ram%C3%A8ne%20dans%20le%20droit%20chemin.&text=Apr%C3%A8s%20avoir%20d%C3%A9croch%C3%A9%20son%20dipl%C3%B4me,du%20Premier%20ministre%20Georges%20Pompidou.).

i.e.

> Decidedly attracted by **the open sea**, the young Chirac embarks as a sailor on a freighter, before his father brings him back on the right track.

There is also a nice article about *open sea*, *grand large*, *haute mer* available for download here: https://journals.openedition.org/bagf/2053

By the way, I found also that *grand large* could have another sense in the past (rare nevertheless)

> Vieux et rare. [En parlant d'un tissu] Au grand large. En grande largeur. Ayez la bonté de m'acheter (...) une aune de lévantine noire au grand large : c'est pour faire un tablier sans couture (Sand, Corresp., t. 1, 1829, p. 75).

according to https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/large